# Using Pretender with Ember CLI

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, ember-simple-auth

I am trying to get our authentication ([`ember-simple-auth`](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth)) to be mocked by [`Pretender`](https://github.com/trek/pretender) to run in our tests, but for some reason I get the following error:

`Pretender intercepted POST http://api.dev/token but no handler was defined for this type of request`

Here is the setup I have at the  moment in my `login-test.js`

```
module('Integration - Login Page', {
  setup: function() {
    App = startApp();
    server = new Pretender(function(){
      this.get('http://api.dev/v1/accounts/current', function(request) {
        var response = {
          "message": "unauthorized"
        };

        return [401, { "Content-Type": "application/json" }, JSON.stringify(response)];
      });

      this.post('http://api.dev/token', function(request) {
        var response = {
          "access_token": "myaccesstoken==",
          "token_type": "bearer"
        };

        return [200, { "Content-Type": "application/json" }, JSON.stringify(response)];
      });
    });
  },
  teardown: function() {
    Ember.run(App, App.destroy);
    server.shutdown();
  }
});
```

Would anyone know why the url is not registering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `http://api.dev` if you are using the server proxy

Comment: I did have it starting with a trailing slash, as `/token`, but I had the same problem. I'm curious if I should set `serverTokenEndpoint` to `/token` and then set a proxy to `http://api.dev`?

Comment: Yup that didi it. I'm going to proxy all requests. Thanks bcardarella!

Comment: unfortunately this solution does't work for me, i wonder what's different in my case

Comment: what is this server proxy you guys are mentioning here?